# how to add values in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: python, api, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

So Im trying to figure out the google spreadsheet api specifically how to add values

I read the documentation but am running into problems .

This is what I have so far

```
values = [
    [
        ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
        ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
        ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
        ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
        ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
    ],
    
]
data = [
    {
        'range': Sheet1!A1:D5,
        'values': values
    },
    
]
body = {
    'valueInputOption': Raw,
    'data': data
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('totalUpdatedCells')))
```

it brings an error saying that the "=" sign next to values is an invalid syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, from your script, the error of `it brings an error saying that the "=" sign next to values is an invalid syntax.` cannot be replicated. I thought that your script in your question is different from the script for replicating your issue. If it's so, can you update your question? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. By the way, do you want to achieve your goal using [googleapis with python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)? I would like to think of the solution by correctly understanding about your issue.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do this with python but  the script I showed above is identical to the one I was compiling

Comment: You have one pair of square brackets too much around your values.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the script I showed above is identical to the one I was compiling`. And also, I cannot replicate your issue of `it brings an error saying that the "=" sign next to values is an invalid syntax.`. When I could replicate your issue, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.